# String Indices Must be Integers - Fetching data from API

Tags: python

Here is the data i want to get from

```
import json

url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/elonpunkyachtclub/stats"

headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
data = response.json
decoded = json.loads(data)

{
  "stats": {
    "one_day_volume": 3.4598559686941988,
    "one_day_change": -0.26082160690977335,
    "one_day_sales": 167,
    "one_day_average_price": 0.020717700411342507,
    "seven_day_volume": 24.111522658583088,
    "seven_day_change": 60.74608045431068,
    "seven_day_sales": 1284,
    "seven_day_average_price": 0.01877844443814882,
    "thirty_day_volume": 24.502017447583082,
    "thirty_day_change": 0,
    "thirty_day_sales": 1370,
    "thirty_day_average_price": 0.017884684268308818,
    "total_volume": 24.50201744758308,
    "total_sales": 1370,
    "total_supply": 6969,
    "count": 6969,
    "num_owners": 1854,
    "average_price": 0.017884684268308818,
    "num_reports": 4,
    "market_cap": 130.86697928945915,
    "floor_price": 0.022
  }
}
```

```py
print(data)
print(data['stats']['floor_price'])
```

I want to fetch the floor price from the data

Getting error, what I am doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.......

Comment: Sounds like you got JSON and didn't [parse it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: Show the code where you invoke the API

Comment: Your data seems to be a string. You have to use `json.loads()` or `.json()` if you are using `requests`.

Comment: You don't need the json module for this. *data = response.json()*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, it seems that you are operating on a string, not decoded data. Try decoding first:

```py
import json

# ... get data

decoded = json.loads(data)
print(decoded['stats']['floor_price'])
```

Comment: I am getting different error, here is full code 

`import json

url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/elonpunkyachtclub/stats"

headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
data = response.json
decoded = json.loads(data)

print(decoded)
print(decoded['stats']['floor_price'])`

Comment: @TrayanshAgarwal I see, the mistake is elsewhere. `response.json` is a function, you should call it using parentheses: `response.json()`. Then you don't have to do `json.loads` since `data` will contain parsed JSON.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, i realised it now